# Opening a VBA UserForm using VBScript?

Tags: excel, vba, vbscript

So I've been working on a project in Excel that creates a UserForm in order to run three different macros. The Userform has been created but the issue I'm facing right now is that whenever I use a script.vbs to open the macro from outside Excel, it closes instantly. I want the UserForm to stay on the screen. Any ideas on how to do this?

Here is the VBS script I'm using.

```
Dim xlApp, xlBook

Set xlApp = CreateObject("Excel.Application")
Set xlBook = xlApp.Workbooks.Open("Path~", True)
xlApp.Run "ThisWorkbook.UserForm"
xlBook.Close
xlApp.Quit

Set xlBook = Nothing
Set xlApp = Nothing

WScript.Quit
```

Here is the Macro code for the Userform.

```
Sub UserForm()

Dim form As New Userform1

form.Show vbModal

End Sub
```

UPDATE: Never mind. I'm an idiot. The solution is to make sure your Excel file is readable, then run it from administrator.

Comment: :) Good that you worked out what it was. To close this thread, please either add your answer and accept it as an answer: this could help others (recommended) or remove the post (not recommended)

Answer (score 0):

Make sure your userform is modal and run the script as administrator.

Answer (score 0):

the Reason is vbModal.

try without vbModal.

```
Sub UserForm()

Dim form As New Userform1

form.Show 

End Sub
```